# Can't fix this ampscript personalization If/then, trying to differentiate between "year" and "years" following anniversary giving date

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Time has flown since you joined our community `%%[ var @startDate, @endDate, @diffYear set @startDate = [First Gift Date] set @endDate = Now() set @diffYear = dateDiff(@startDate, @endDate,"Y") @yearText = IF(@diffYear == 1, "year", "years" )%%[ENDIF]%%` ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```ampscript
%%[

set @debug = 1  /* set this to 0 to disable debugging output */
set @startDate = AttributeValue("first gift date")
set @startDate = "2021-01-01" /* remove this line after testing */
set @endDate = Now()
set @diff = dateDiff(@startDate, @endDate,"Y")

if @debug == 1 then 
  output(concat("<br>startDate: ",@startDate))
  output(concat("<br>endDate: ",@endDate))
  output(concat("<br>diff: ",@diff,"<br>"))
endif 

if @diff > 1 then
  set @unit = concat(@diff, " years")
else 
  set @unit = "a year"
endif
]%%
Time has flown since you joined our community %%=v(@unit)=%% ago.
```

**Output**:

```
startDate: 2021-01-01
endDate: 1/18/2023 9:33:02 AM
diff: 2
Time has flown since you joined our community 2 years ago.
```

**Try it yourself**: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/2ens1zz7

Comment: This was VERY helpful thank you! I'm still struggling to generate an output that is an exact number (ex 4 years) with this script...

Comment: Updated my example to include the diff output.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate the help!